# How to set default save location in applications

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop, shortcuts, dreamweaver

Especially in dreamweaver and photoshop.
And do you know of any application that lets me jump through all the common save locations for dreamweaver.
For example, I save .php files on `C:\Wamp\www.`
And then I created a new site, which will has default save location to be:`C:\Users\username\Documents\Unnamed Site 2`

Answer (score 1):

This is up to each application to manage.

I have never heard of an application that lets you manipulate settings of other applications default save locations and would be quite surprised if anyone turned up.